# gvim in windows, need to preserve or correct path casing (e.g., c:\windows vs. C:\Windows)

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

I use gvim in a windows environment and have ClearCase for source control.

My problem is that windows paths aren't case-sensitive, however, ClearCase enforces case sensitivity. So, when editing a file in gvim, the path isnt necessarily cased properly (e.g., c:\WiNdOwS\Something.txt vs. C:\Windows\Something.txt), so when I try to check the file out the current working file in gvim via the command line, ClearCase barfs and complains that it can't find the file.

```
C:\WiNdOwS\Something.txt --> C:\Windows\Something.txt
   ^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^
```

Is there any way to:

1. make vim autocorrect path casing, or,
2. make clearcase not care about casing

Right now I have to either make sure the path case is correct or open windows explorer whenever I want to do anything to a file that's source control-related... which totally sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`expand('%:p')`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand%28%29). That should give you the current file name expanded to the full path.

From what I've seen it also returns a string with the correct case on MS windows, but I haven't tried that myself.

If expand doesn't work, you'll probably have to reach down in to the win32 API to get the correct case for the path, something like [GetFullPathName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm not sure if it is possible to use that directly from vim (without hacking the vim source code), but if you wrap that up into a small program you could certainly call that from vim. If your vim is compiled with Python support, you could use Python's [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module to call win32 functions.

Comment: That doesn't correct the casing for the full path, perhaps only the filename. I say "perhaps" because the filename casing is already corrected when I open the file, so I can't verify that it explicitly corrects it (though I suspect it might). The incorrect casing remains, however, in the path to the file, e.g., C:\testdir\bAdCaSiNg\goodCasing.txt.

Comment: I've edited the question to more clearly state the problem.

Comment: You might have to reach down into the win32 API see updated answer.